# MSSQL - Running sum with reset after gap

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have been trying to solve a problem for a few days now, but I just can't get it solved. Hence my question today.
I would like to calculate the running sum in the following table. My result so far looks like this:

| PersonID | Visit_date | Medication_intake | Previous_date | Date_diff | Running_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-26 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2012-11-16 | 1 | 2012-04-26 | 204 | 204 |
| 1 | 2013-04-11 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2013-07-19 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2013-12-05 | 1 | 2013-07-19 | 139 | 343 |
| 1 | 2014-03-18 | 1 | 2013-12-05 | 103 | **585** |
| 1 | 2014-06-24 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2014-12-01 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2015-03-09 | 1 | 2014-12-01 | 98 | 98 |
| 2 | 2015-09-28 | 0 |  |  |  |

This is my desired result. So only the running sum over contiguous blocks (Medication_intake=1) should be calculated.

| PersonID | Visit_date | Medication_intake | Previous_date | Date_diff | Running_sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2012-04-26 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2012-11-16 | 1 | 2012-04-26 | 204 | 204 |
| 1 | 2013-04-11 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2013-07-19 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 1 | 2013-12-05 | 1 | 2013-07-19 | 139 | 139 |
| 1 | 2014-03-18 | 1 | 2013-12-05 | 103 | **242** |
| 1 | 2014-06-24 | 0 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2014-12-01 | 1 |  |  |  |
| 2 | 2015-03-09 | 1 | 2014-12-01 | 98 | 98 |
| 2 | 2015-09-28 | 0 |  |  |  |

I work with Microsoft SQL Server 2019 Express.

Thank you very much for your tips!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a gaps and islands problem, and one approach uses the difference in row numbers method:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID
                                 ORDER BY Visit_date) rn1,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PersonId, Medication_intake
                                 ORDER BY Visit_date) rn2
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT PersonID, Visit_date, Medication_intake, Previous_date, Date_diff,
       CASE WHEN Date_diff IS NOT NULL AND Medication_intake = 1
            THEN SUM(Date_diff) OVER (PARTITION BY PersonID, rn1 - rn2
                                      ORDER BY Visit_date) END AS Running_sum
FROM cte
ORDER BY PersonID, Visit_date;
```

### Demo

The `CASE` expression in the outer query computes the rolling sum for date diff along islands of records having a medication intake value of 1.  For other records, or for records where date diff be null, the value generated is simply null.